# Loading font fron CloudFront giving No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, cross-domain, amazon-cloudfront

First, I know there are tons of similar issues on StackOverflow and elsewhere. I tried them for days with no luck. So sorry if this sounds duplicate. Correct me if it is actually.

I have Heroku Rails app loading font from CloudFront. Everything else seems to load fine except that font. I get

> Access to Font at
>   'https://domainname.herokuapp.com/assets/LigatureSymbols-2.11-722bc1af51c5e458d52834d798e4c0e8.ttf'
>   from origin **'null'** has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

It says origin **null**, and **access-control-allow-origin** is not present. However this is the request and response data:

```
Request URL:https://domainname-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/LigatureSymbols-2.11-722bc1af51c5e458d52834d798e4c0e8.ttf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:151.101.0.249:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Age:52
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 16 Apr 2017 10:40:37 GMT
Location:https://domainname.herokuapp.com/assets/LigatureSymbols-2.11-722bc1af51c5e458d52834d798e4c0e8.ttf
Server:gunicorn/19.7.1
Via:1.1 varnish
Via:1.1 vegur, 1.1 vegur
X-Cache:HIT
X-Cache-Hits:1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Served-By:cache-hhn1527-HHN
X-Timer:S1492339237.333330,VS0,VE0
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:domainname-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net
**Origin:https://staging.domainname.com**
Referer:https://domainname.herokuapp.com/assets/application-d2b73eea67437c851b6e71803bad2a6c.css
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Name
?store=true&search_type=posts
css?family=Lato:400,300,700
MgNNr5y1C_tIEuLEmicLmwLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff2
LigatureSymbols-2.11-722bc1af51c5e458d52834d798e4c0e8.ttf
MDadn8DQ_3oT6kvnUq_2r_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2
icon-close-89c814d2fa53dff86b00936a7a8c836e.png
icon-bell-91b2c7d5db27d9fc9e8325dda55e73c0.png
icon-comment-35728eedd10ff36bc89c7a977ed67764.png
```

Origin is defined, and it should be allowing all origins. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you can see, your Fastly CDN is redirecting you. Are you sure your heroku instance serve the header?

Comment: thanks... that seems to be the problem. Will dig more into it.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi ok, it's fixed after I tinkered with Fastly settings. I think what solved it was added the specific domain to the Domains list. Want to put your reply as answer so I can accept it?